# Description of skew-symmetric matrix in Wikipedia

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, soft-question, symmetric-matrices

Consider real matrices.

In wikipedia we have a [statement about symmetric  matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetric_matrix#Real_symmetric_matrices).

"Every symmetric matrix is thus, up to choice of an orthonormal basis, a diagonal matrix"

For skew-symmetric matrices is also [presented real form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skew-symmetric_matrix#Spectral_theory), but block diagonal one (denote it as $K_1$),

Now the entries of this form can be presented via appropriate permutations in the form $K_2=PK_1P^T$ where they are grouped on **anti-diagonal**

for example:

$\begin{bmatrix}  0 & 0  & 0 & 1 \\  0 & 1  & 0 & 0 \\  1 & 0  & 0 & 0 \\  0 
& 0  & 1 & 0 \end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}  0 & -a & 0 & 0 \\  a & 0  & 0 & 0\\  0 & 0  & 0 & -b \\  0 & 0  & b & 0 \end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}  0 & 0 & 1 & 0\\  0 & 1  & 0 & 0 \\  0 & 0  & 0 & 1\\  1 & 0  & 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix}= \begin{bmatrix}  0 & 0  & 0 & b\\  0 & 0  & a & 0 \\  0 & -a & 0 & 0\\  -b & 0  & 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix} $

hence:

- is it reasonable to add a comment in wikipedia for a sake of  analogy  with symmetric matrix entry:

"Every skew-symmetric matrix is thus, up to choice of an orthonormal basis, a anti-diagonal (skew-symmetric) matrix" ?

What do you think ? Would be such statement  useful to the degree that it is recommended to add it to Wikipedia ? Has it some advantages which are not immediately visible in block diagonal form?

Comment: I think that it is a correct statement. Maybe place it somewhere it can be easily contrasted with the statement about symmetric matrices. I don't know if it has any advantages to the block diagonal form, but it at least highlights an important property of matrices.

Comment: @ZachFavakeh Thank You for the encouragement. It were even more interesting if it would be linked with some specific properties of antidiagonal matrices.